# Is there any command that points me to the kubeconfig file in k8s/openshift

Tags: python, linux, kubernetes, openshift

Is there any command which points me to the path where kubeconfig file is present?
I mean I am working on python k8s/openshift client. I am looking for linux or python command or libraries which can print me the path where kubeconfig file is present.

By default kubeconfig is present it home most of the time, but it may also vary for different deployment types.

looking forward to any suggestions/concerns.

Comment: Why do you need to know?  The [standard Kubernetes SDKs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) have built-in logic to find it; [Organizing Cluster Access Using kubeconfig Files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/) in the Kubernetes documentation describes the standard rules.

Answer (score 1):

kubectl configuration file is located at ~/. kube/config as default. You can check using this code

```
kubeconfig_path = os.environ.get('KUBECONFIG', '~/.kube/config')
```

You can check if the variable is set

```
kubeconfig_path = os.environ['KUBECONFIG']
```

and if it's not you can try setting this

```
os.environ["KUBECONFIG"]=your_config_file_path
```

Answer (score 1):

I used an installer to install the K8's cluster.
In my case, it is to be found under oauth folder. (I am not sure about the full correct path) but you can take a look in your k8's folder structure.

Or use the command find in linux to locate the file.

something like: `find / -type f -name '*.kubeconfig'`

Comment: Thanks
This is okay, but if we have multiple kubeconfig files i.e. kubeconfig and kunbeconfig2. 
How we can check the original kubeconfig.

Comment: hm.. not sure about how to verify the original file but what I would do is verify the content of each kubeconfig file one per one. Then verify which might be the original file (by taking a look at specifications etc..). Normally the .kubeconfig file is created when you run the installer. In this case, I would also check the creation time of the file and compare it with others to see which one is first created. Please note that these are just some steps that might help you.